How would I display the height of each bar in a bar graph using python-pptx library?
I'm trying to automate the creation of some bar graphs, and I'm able to do everything except display the height of each bar above it. Here is the code I have so far:
def add_bar_chart_slides():
    prs = Presentation()

    slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]  # Use the layout for title and content
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4']
    chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (581, 581, 243, 121))
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(.5), Inches(8), Inches(6.5)  # Position and size of the chart
    chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
        XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
    ).chart


    for i, point in enumerate(chart.series[0].points):
        fill = point.format.fill
        fill.solid()
        if i == 0:
            fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 112, 192)  # RGB value for blue
        else:
            fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(191, 191, 191)  # RGB value for gray



But I'm not able to figure out how to add the y labels above each bar like in the screenshot below. Can someone help me with this?

